# Does FastMM only report memory leaked and/or memory allocated?

Tags: delphi, memory-leaks, delphi-xe, fastmm, resource-leak

I am debugging my program with FastMM and it seems that a lot of the memory leaks it is reporting seem legitimate memory allocation not an actually memory leak.

For instance,

```
A memory block has been leaked. The size is: 20

This block was allocated by thread 0xD44, and the stack trace (return addresses) at the time was:
404902 [System.pas][System][@GetMem][3693]
406597 [System.pas][System][TObject.NewInstance][11044]
406B2A [System.pas][System][@ClassCreate][12121]
60A1D2 [CtrlObjs.pas][Ctrlobjs][TConnObj.Create][430]
61703B [Control.pas][Control][TControlMgr.FindLinks][854]
60ACB2 [CtrlObjs.pas][Ctrlobjs][TControlObject.FindLink][746]
60E2A3 [CtrlObjs.pas][Ctrlobjs][TDelayControl.EvalPulse][2105]
60E4C0 [CtrlObjs.pas][Ctrlobjs][TDelayControl.Evaluate][2193]
6102D4 [CtrlObjs.pas][Ctrlobjs][TLineControl.Evaluate][3155]
60ABF1 [CtrlObjs.pas][Ctrlobjs][TControlObject.ActiveCount][711]
6105D8 [CtrlObjs.pas][Ctrlobjs][TLineControl.ActiveCount][3261]

The block is currently used for an object of class: TConnObj
```

TConnObj is class that is frequently used to create an object and be destroyed when the program is not need it anymore. However, FastMM is reporting it to be actual memory leak. So, how do you tell which is which when looking at the FastMM memory leak log file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If FastMM is reporting it as a leak then it really is a leak.

You have created an object and failed to destroy it before the program terminates. Usually this is due to a straightforward error in your code. Perhaps you omitted a try/finally to protect the object's life.

If it's a global scope object that is not being destroyed then you could simply destroy it at program termination. Or you could call [RegisterExpectedMemoryLeak](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Registering_Memory_Leaks) to indicate that you do not intend to destroy that object. But only do that when you intentionally leak an object. Don't use it to paper over a leak that is not intentional.

But the bottom line is that FastMM does not lie. If it says you are leaking, trust it.

Comment: I often have buffer pools that contain thousands of objects that I don't explicitly free at app exit.  I don't fancy passing pointers to all those buffer fields etc. within.  I guess I'll leave leak reporting off :(

Comment: @MartinJames, then I hope no-one will ever have to work on your code. This makes it impossible to check for real leaks.

Comment: @martin It's not as if you have to write thousands of calls to RegisterExpectedMemoryLeak

Comment: @François - usually, every second, a timer dumps the level of every object pool and queue count to a status bar. I know at run time if any pooled objects are leaking or double-released without waiting for any memory manager info.  All my apps shut down immediately and safely, even servers with 20000 clients connected and eight busy threads, because the object pools outlive all the threads - the OS stops all threads first, then deallocates the memory.  My apps don't get memory leaks because I don't create any objects after startup.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - how can I create 1000 objects and have their data members registered? As I explained to Francios, (sorry, don't know how to do the cedilla), I don't need the memory-manager dump much, but if I could get it to work easily, then I would take it's output, yes.

Comment: Scratch that question in he comment - it's somewhat out of the OP context.  I will ask a separate question.